# Como cortar uma string PHP nas tags <h2>

Tags: php, string

Tenho um site de receitas em que os ingredientes são separados em blocos, por exemplo:

```
$ingredientes='<ul>
<li>100g de farinha de trigo</li>
<li>1 ovo</li>
<li>2 pitadas de sal</li>
<li>1 fio de azeite</li>
</ul>
<h2>Molho</h2>
<ul>
<li>Tomate</li>
<li>Cebola</li>
</ul>';
```

Aí eu precisava separar cada bloco para poder criar os campos de input para edição (cada titulo h2 inicia um novo bloco), nesse exemplo ficaria:

```
<textarea name="bloco1"><ul>
    <li>100g de farinha de trigo</li>
    <li>1 ovo</li>
    <li>2 pitadas de sal</li>
    <li>1 fio de azeite</li>
    </ul></textarea>

<input name="titulo2" value="Molho">

<textarea name="bloco2"><ul>
<li>Tomate</li>
<li>Cebola</li>
</ul></textarea>
```

Só que nem sempre serão 2 blocos, as vezes pode ser 2, outras 3, e por ai vai.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você possa usar o XPath, algo como:

```
// Inicia o DOMDocument
$html = new DOMDocument();
// Importa o HTML (do $ingrediente)
$html->loadHTML($ingredientes);

// Inicia o XPath e busca por <ul>
$els = (new DOMXpath($html))->query("//ul");

// Obtém o HTML de cada <ul> e exibe entre <textarea>
foreach ($els as $el) {
    echo "<textarea>" . $el->ownerDocument->saveHTML($el) . "</textarea>";
}
```

Isso irá retornar:

```
<textarea><ul>
<li>100g de farinha de trigo</li>
<li>1 ovo</li>
<li>2 pitadas de sal</li>
<li>1 fio de azeite</li>
</ul>
</textarea>
<textarea><ul>
<li>Tomate</li>
<li>Cebola</li>
</ul></textarea>
```

Neste caso considerei que quer pegar tudo que está no `<ul>`. Se quiser ignorar o `h2` creio que possa usar outro XPath, ou no ruim no ruim pode usar um `*` e verificar no `foreach` se ele é um `h2` e ignora-lo.

---

Com o comentário, você pode simplesmente pegar todos os `ul` e `h2` e alterar a exibição baseado no que ele é.

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($ingredientes);

foreach ((new DOMXpath($html))->query('//ul|//h2') as $el) {
    if(strtolower($el->nodeName) === 'ul') {
          printf('<textarea>%s</textarea>', trim($el->ownerDocument->saveHTML($el)));
    }else{
          printf('<input value="%s">', htmlentities($el->textContent, ENT_HTML5 | ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'));
    }
}
```

Se ele for `ul` ele irá mostrar o HTML dentro do `<textarea>`, se ele for um `input` ele mostrará o conteúdo do `h2` como um valor. *O `$el->ownerDocument->saveHTML($el)` irá retornar o HTML, já o `$el->textContent` retorna apenas o texto.*

> Lembre-se que isto pode ainda estar vulnerável à um XSS!

Resultado:

```
<textarea><ul>
<li>100g de farinha de trigo</li>
<li>1 ovo</li>
<li>2 pitadas de sal</li>
<li>1 fio de azeite</li>
</ul>
</textarea>
<input value="Molho">
<textarea><ul>
<li>Tomate</li>
<li>Cebola</li>
</ul></textarea>
```

[Teste aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f06a4b450f3af123f85152aab7865f2ad123e01c)

Comment: opa, só preciso que retorne o titulo no input tbm

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo eu editei

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma combinação de `explode` com `foreach` para chegar ao resultado desejado. Veja:

```php
<?php

$ingredientes='<ul>
<li>100g de farinha de trigo</li>
<li>1 ovo</li>
<li>2 pitadas de sal</li>
<li>1 fio de azeite</li>
</ul>
<h2>Molho</h2>
<ul>
<li>Tomate</li>
<li>Cebola</li>
</ul>';

$exploded = explode('<h2>', $ingredientes);

foreach ($exploded as $i => $item) 
{
    $partes = explode('</h2>', $item);
    $index = $i + 1;

    /**
     * Se existe o indice 1 é pq tem 2 items
     * Logo existe o titulo e os ingredientes
     */
    if (isset($partes[1])) 
    {
        printf('<input type="text" name="titulo%d" value="%s"/>', $index, trim($partes[0]));
        printf('<textarea name="bloco%d">%s</textarea>', $index, trim($partes[1]));
        continue;
    }
    /**
     * Caso contrario existe somente
     * os ingredientes
     */
    printf('<textarea name="bloco%d">%s</textarea>', $index, trim($partes[0]));
}
```